# Copy files to an EC2 instance which doesn't have a key pair

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, copy

Please let me know if there is a way to copy files to an EC2 instance using the aws cli or any other means.
Ec2 instances i am referring here are not attached with any key pair, so we cannot do scp.

Comment: The Amazon EC2 instance is just like any other computer running the same operating system. If you want to 'send' something to the instance, you will need _something_ on the computer that can 'receive' the file. It is often easier to have the EC2 instance 'download' a file itself rather than attempting to 'upload' a file to an EC2 instance. For example, if the file was copied to Amazon S3, then you could run an AWS CLI command on the EC2 instance to then download it from S3.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you've got correct Linux user:

For Amazon Linux, the user name is ec2-user.
For RHEL, the user name is ec2-user or root.
For Ubuntu, the user name is ubuntu or root.
For Centos, the user name is centos.
For Fedora, the user name is ec2-user.
For SUSE, the user name is ec2-user or root.
Otherwise, if ec2-user and root don’t work, check with your AMI provider.

If copying without a key pair, omit the flag -i(scp -i), and type in the password of the user when prompted.

Alternatively try transfer using SFTP

Start a secure FTP connection with the instance using the following command: msftp @<instance_id>

Use 'put' to copy your files to the instance using: put /path/to/source /path/to/destination

exit

I haven't done it personally but it seems the way to go.